# Filling Score Cells on Gradtable

Tags: exam

How to put the maximum ``scores'' of the solutions and total of them on the gradtable score?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{put}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\ds\displaystyle
\parindent0em

\printanswers 
\newcommand{\class}{MATEMATIKA}
\newcommand{\examnum}{\large\bfseries Penskoran Penilaian Tengah Semester Ganjil}
\newcommand{\examdate}{\today}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\class}{\examnum}{\examdate}
\runningheader{\class}{\examnum}{Hal. \thepage\ dari \numpages}
\runningfooter{}{}{}
\runningheadrule

\pointpoints{exam-point}{poin}
\pointpoints{bobot}{bobot}
\hqword{No. Soal}
\hpword{Bobot Soal}
\htword{Jumlah}
\hsword{Skor Maksimum} % the score on gradtable
\qformat{\bfseries Soal Nomor \thequestion\hspace{14cm} bobot = \totalpoints\hfill}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Jawaban:}\enspace}

\begin{document}

\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}%

\addpoints 
\begin{center}
\gradetable[h]
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
\question[15] 
The question for number one.
    \begin{solution}
The solution
\flushright \textbf{Skor maksimum = 6}
    \end{solution}

 \question[10] 
The question for number two.
\begin{solution}
The solution
\flushright \textbf{Skor maksimum = 3}
   \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Like this the solutions.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how "bobot = 15"  and "skor maksimum = 6"  correlate?

Comment: "bobot" means weight and "skor maksimum" means maximum score. I also don't understand the correlation between them. They seem to be redundant!

Comment: ``Bobot'' indicates the difficulty level of a problem and ''skor'' indicates the algorithm to answer it. (Yes, skor maksimum means maximum score.)